# Passing an Exception to an HttpHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler, webclient

I am trying to pass an exception to an HttpHandler by doing the following:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    byte[] exceptionData;

    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter(null, new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.Persistence));
    formatter.Serialize(stream, e);
    exceptionData = stream.ToArray();

    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    Uri handler = new Uri(ApplicationUri, "TransferException.axd");

    #if DEBUG
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(BypassAllCertificateStuff);
    #endif

    try
    {
        client.UploadData(handler, exceptionData);
    }
    catch (WebException) { }
}
```

**EDIT**

I am getting the following exception on the client.UploadData() line.
"Content-Length or Chunked Encoding cannot be set for an operation that does not write data."

**EDIT**

Even if I change my call to be client.UploadString(location, "THIS IS A TEST!"); it still fails with the same exception.

Comment: Side point: all the `IDisposable` objects there should be in `using` statements

Comment: What line throws that content-length related exception?

Comment: Sorry, the client.UploadData() throws the exception.

Comment: what is the code of transferexception.axd ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was due to a .Net registered AXD handler. When I changed the extension to .axdx everything started working.

Answer (score 0):

I bet that because you're never closing your stream, your array is of zero length.

---

Try this:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    byte[] exceptionData;

    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter(
            null, new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.Persistence));
        formatter.Serialize(stream, ex);
        exceptionData = stream.ToArray();
    }

    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        Uri handler = new Uri(ApplicationUri, "TransferException.axd");

#if DEBUG
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
            new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(BypassAllCertificateStuff);
#endif

        client.UploadData(handler, exceptionData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, I copied and pasted this code and still received the same exception. It's odd, I can't find any references to this exception message on the web.

Comment: @Chris: my next step would be to confirm that `exceptionData.Length` is non-zero at the time of the `UploadData` call. Note also that the docs say "This member outputs trace information when you enable network tracing in your application. For more information, see [Network Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyb3xww8.aspx)." I would also break in the debugger and confirm what's in the `Headers` property before the call. Finally, I'd comment out the certificate validation handler for now, just to simplify things.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be the issue because even if I change my .UploadData() call to client.UploadString(location, "THIS IS A TEST!"); it still fails.

Comment: @Chris: Ok, then I would definitely remove the `ServicePointManager` stuff, then wrap the call in a `try { ... } catch (Exception ex){Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());}` then post the full exception here. Remove the try/catch when done debugging.

Comment: @alhambraeidos: I have no idea. That's what was in the original question.

Comment: @alhambraeidos: Take a look at this http://flimflan.com/blog/SafelyRunningBackgroundThreadsInASPNET20.aspx

Comment: @Chris: note that the article is about .NET 2.0, and there may be better solutions in later releases.